# Grubby fatal error in Linux kernel installation

Tags: kernel, compiling, system-installation, kernel-modules

I have compiled Linux kernel 2.6.24.6 from source (without problem) and tried to install it. Specifically, after unpacking the Linux source code, I did

```
make && make modules
```

to compile. Then after some configuration, I simply used

```
sudo make modules_install install
```

to install the newly built binary. During this process, there is an error about locating file `/sys/class/net/eth0/device/bus`. It also throws grubby fatal error. Detailed error stack is as follows:

```
sh /mnt/factor/myProj3/linux-2.6.24.6/arch/x86/boot/install.sh 2.6.24.6 arch/x86/boot/bzImage System.map "/boot"
unable to stat /sys/class/net/eth0/device/bus: No such file or directory
WARNING: No module xenblk found for kernel 2.6.24.6, continuing anyway
grubby fatal error: unable to find a suitable template
```

The source code should be all right. What could be the cause of this fatal error? Without fixing it, I can't get Linux installed. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the bug list at

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=124246

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=730357

Both of them talk of creating a grub template file at /etc/default/grub , while also making sure if any of the other grub defaults or options to be made into this file.

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="Fedora"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="LANG=en_US.UTF-8 SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 KEYBOARDTYPE=pc
```

Or edit /boot/grub/grub.conf manually and add those lines into the configuration to save you some sleep.